# Creating symbolic links

Tags: file-management, symbolic-link, vifm

How does one create a symbolic link in vifm? The documentation and help file mention no word of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this in my .vifm/vifmrc:

```
COMMAND=ln=!ln -s %d/%f %D
```

this way when you call :ln, a link of the selected file is made in the other directory (if you are in split view).  it even works with multiple files selected with visual (v) or tag (t).

Answer (score 3):

For vifm version 0.8 you can add this to `.vifm/vifmrc`:

```
command ln ln -s %f:p %D
```

Then you can type `:ln` hit enter and symbolic link(s) of the file or directory under cursor (or selected files or directories) will be created in the directory of the other window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific command, but you can execute any command using:

```
:! <command>
```

such as:

```
:! ln -s /media/usb usb
```